# Vector equations

Tags: vector, differential-equations

System of equations
a)

```
[latex]\begin{cases} x_{1}^{''}-3x_1-4x_2=0\\x_{2}^{''}+x_1+x_2=0\end{cases}[latex]
```

write as one first-order vector equation.

When I simplified it, I got it `$x_{1}^{''}+3x_{2}^{''}-x_2=0.$`

Next, I have a second-order equation on how to bring it down to the first.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is there a computer algebra system (even a pseudo one like matlab) involved somewhere? Else this question is off-topic and belongs to math.SE, where you also have mathjax for latex. But put some more effort into your solution attempt, what is the reason to reduce an explicit system to an implicit one? Or are you trying to find a scalar 4th order DE for one of the components?